# How can I find the next uppercase word in a list?

Tags: python, list, logic

I have an assignment where I have to read in the entire script of Romeo & Juliet and print out which lines have both the words Romeo and Juliet in them. From there I have to find who said those lines. I have the play being read in reverse with `rev_line = lines[::-1]` so the next all uppercase word from the list would be the name that I need but I'm not sure how to get to the next all uppercase word. Code is as follows:

```
play = open('L19_data_romeojuliet.txt').read()
lines = play.split('\n')
romandju = []
for n in lines:
    if n.count('Romeo') >= 1 and n.count('Juliet')>= 1:
        romandju.append(n)

rev_line = lines[::-1]
for i in rev_line:
```

Comment: Why would the next uppercase word be the person that said it? There are plenty of uppercase words that might not be the name of a person.

Comment: I agree with that @IainShelvington said. In any case, some input data would be good. See: [mcve]. Also, use a context manager to handle files.

Comment: @IainShelvington thanks for the response. For example the file reads: 
                                                                                                                        
    PRINCE

    For never was a story of more woe
    Than this of Juliet and her Romeo.                                                                  *there are 5 lines that I need to identify the speaker for and so I was thinking if I can identify the next uppercase word from the line I've already found while the file is being read in reverse than I'd have my answers.